# MySQL Database query parameters in MATLAB

Tags: mysql, database, matlab, jdbc

I am using JDBC in MATLAB to connect to MySQL Database and want to use some external parameters within the query, it worked for me with single numeric parameter but I want to use more than one and strings parameters.

```
parameter1 = 12;
query = ['select name from Users where user_password=' parameter1 ];          
curs = exec(conn,query);
curs = fetch(curs);
x = curs.Data;
```

Comment: How does your code for multiple parameters look like and what is the intended sql query you want to generate?

Comment: I have no idea how to write that query, the only query that worked for me is the one above. and I want someone to tell me how to add another parameter (I mean like password) to the query.

Comment: [Read the manual](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp)

Comment: Mate I know how to use sql queries in MySQL but I am asking about writing them inside MATLAB. I have use sql queries in JAVA, C++, C# and PHP and their were lots of online resources to learn but for MATLAB is very rear  and limited.

Comment: @Hussein His point is that the sql syntax is *exactly* the same in MATLAB. You just have to construct the query string. `query = sprintf('SELECT name FROM Users WHERE user_password=''%s'' AND name=''%s''', parameter1, parameter2)`?

Comment: I asked you if you know how the intended query should look like and you said you had no idea. If you know how the query should look like, put this information into your question. For example "I want a query like `SELECT name FROM Users WHERE user_password=12 AND user_name=tom`"

Comment: Sorry I miss understood you first, Thank you @Daniel